# jQuery validation addClassRules returns NaN instead of max value

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, coffeescript

I made a custom validation rule for my elements with the class "age" (note: I know that I can make a basic rule using the name attribute, but it's not what I'm looking for here).

My code looks like that (CoffeeScript) :

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules
  age:
    required: true
    min: 10
    max: parseInt($('#max_age').data('max'), 10)
```

When I try `parseInt($('#max_age').data('max'), 10)`in the Chrome console, it returns the correct value, perfectly parsed.

However, my validation rule doesn't seem to be working… I get the error "Please enter a value less than or equal to NaN" on my input '.age'.

So to summarize, the validation rule works for 'required' and 'min', but I don't seem to be able to use a custom value for my 'max' parameter.

Does anyone have any idea ? I checked [the jQuery validation documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addClassRules#namerules), but they only use numeric values in their examples.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

This should help.

In your validation js

**Change**

```
// clean number parameters
$.each(['minlength', 'maxlength', 'min', 'max'], function() {
    if (rules[this]) {
        rules[this] = Number(rules[this]);
    }
});
```

**With**

```
  // clean number parameters
    $.each(['minlength', 'maxlength'], function() {
        if (rules[this]) {
            rules[this] = Number(rules[this]);
        }
    });
```

else upgrade your validation js with latest version

source : https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/455